# how can I use decorator for method variable inside class in nestjs?

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, decorator

```
import {isNotEmpty} from "class-validator";

export Service   {

create(createdto)
{
const {name,age} = createdto;

@isNotEmpty()
name          //using decorator to check whether name is null or 
undefined
} 
}
```

Since, the decorator is only useful to class methods, I cannot use it inside method variables.
How can it validate the method variables?

Comment: learn about decorators here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html This isn't related to nestjs

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. You can absolutely have property decorators. That's what [class-validator](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator) is based on

Comment: Please, fix issues in your text.

Comment: Thank for clearing up..i have now  put  decorator in the  service class method  to validate its method  member

Comment: Where do you want to call `validate`?

Comment: inside the service class method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that decorators on local variables are not supported by language (ECMAScript2016/Typescript), you can not utilize decorators in your service the way it is described in the question.

Still, class-validator provides non-decorator implementation for its validation functions.

On Github of class-validator: https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#manual-validation is written:

> There are several method exist in the Validator that allows to perform non-decorator based validation:

```
import { isEmpty, isBoolean } from 'class-validator';

isEmpty(value); isBoolean(value);
```

So, you can achieve same goal with code like this:

```
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { CreateDto } from "./dto/create.dto";
import { isEmpty, isInt } from "class-validator";

@Injectable()
export class TestValidationService {
  test(createDto: CreateDto) {
    const {name, age} = createDto;
    
    if (isEmpty(name)) {
      throw "There is no name.";
    }
    
    if (!isInt(age)) {
      throw "Age is not int."
    }
    
    return createDto;
  }
}
```

Finally, if it doesn't suit you to utilize one-by-one method inside the service, you can still decorate your DTO, and utilize validate method from the class-validator.

Like this:

```
import { IsInt, IsNotEmpty } from "class-validator";

export class CreateDto {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  name: string;
  
  @IsInt()
  age: number
}
```

And in your service:

```
async testWithValidate(createDto: CreateDto) {
    const validationResult = await validate(createDto);
}
```